# Как добавить клонированный элемент из DOM в JS. При добавлении элемента скопированного через el.cloneNode выдаётся ошибка

Tags: javascript, dom

[image: Экран ошибки]
[image: Экран со HTML разметкой]

При добавлении элемента скопированного через el.cloneNode выдаётся ошибка

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')`

Подскажите, как добавить клонированный элемент из Dom в JS.

```
function sendCard() {
    var news = document.getElementById('s1');
    var inprocess = document.getElementById('s2');
    var card = document.getElementById('btnsend').parentNode;
    if (card.parentNode == news) {
        var inprocess = document.getElementById('s2');
        var copycard = card.cloneNode(true);
        console.log(copycard);
        news.removeChild(card);
        inprocess.appendChild(copycard);
    } else {
        if (card.parentNode == inprocess) {
            inprocess.removeChild(card);
            var done = document.getElementById('s3');
            var copycard = card.cloneNode(true);
            console.log(copycard);
            done.appendChild(card);
        } else {
            var done = document.getElementById('s3');
            done.removeChild(card);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: или упростите код в вопросе, убрав лишние дивы и переменные не относящиеся к сути вопроса, либо добавьте разметку, либо укажите сообщение об ошибке, а еще лучше сделайте это все сразу

Answer (score 1):

В связи с тем, что в вопросе не приведены разметка и стили в тестовом формате, нет возможности воспроизведения оригинальной ошибки.

Ошибка на скринах вопроса говорит что элемент которому Вы хотите добавить `card` равен `null` (в конкретном случае не ясно где 70 строка но там ошибка, либо тут:

```
inprocess.appendChild(copycard);
```

либо тут:

```
done.appendChild(card);
```

Я создал абстрактный пример клонирования кнопки с дивом - для демонстрации клонирования без ошибки, и ответа на основной вопрос:

> как добавить клонированный элемент из DOM в
> JS. При добавлении элемента скопированного через el.cloneNode выдаётся
> ошибка

Несмотря на то, что клонирование глубокое обработчики событий в него не включаются, их нужно добавлять отдельно.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

const cloning = ({target}) => {
  const child  = target.parentNode.cloneNode(true)
  child.addEventListener('click', cloning, false)
  document.body.appendChild(child)
}

button.addEventListener('click', cloning, false)
```

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>клонировать</button>
<div>
```